# What do I need to install Microsoft.Bot.Builder.4.0.8?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, botframework

I'm trying to install the BotFramework 4.08 from nuget but I get the following error:

"Could not install package 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder 4.0.8'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework."

4.6.1 is supposed to be okay for .NET Standard 2.0, so why am I getting this error? I'm using VS 2015

Comment: You might switch latest NuGet and Visual Studio to use .NET Standard 2.0 on .NET Framework 4.6.1 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/17/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7-1/ Read "BCL - .NET Standard 2.0 Support" section for more details for Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Lex Li in comments, this is a limitation of netstandard libraries within .NET Framework projects lower than 4.7.1 in Visual Studio 2015.  Options are:

- Switch to Visual Studio 2017
- Manually install https://aka.ms/netstandard-build-support-netfx (NuGet 3.6 will prompt you for this automatically)
- Change the target framework of the project to .NET 4.7.1